# I Need a way to execute a particular function when i press the forward key or the back key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a way to execute a particular function when I press the forward key or the back key in javascript.  So that it may work when the forward button is pressed it may execute the function but it should work without taking the input in any type of text box.

I mean it should work on the whole page no matter where I am on the page but if I press the forward button the function should be executed.

I know how to do it by taking an input in a text box by matching the key codes but don't know how to make it work in someway else.

Comment: i tried onkeypress="myFunction()" but it doesnt work when i tried to make it work for any button

Comment: What forward and back "keys" are you talking about?  What does a textbox have to do with this question?  Do you mean the forward and back buttons on your browser's toolbar?  Or do you mean special keys on your keyboard?  Maybe you can use `onkeypress` on the `document` instead of just in the textbox?

Comment: you mean the browser's forward/back buttons?

Comment: Can you display what you have so far? Display the relevant source code can helps us understand what you wish to accomplish, it will also give us the chance to explain to you why it isn't functioning as intended. No source code = nothing to work with.

Comment: Maybe you mean the arrow keys? I think the answer is just: `document.onkeypress = function(e) { }` then whatever code you already have goes in that function

Comment: Thank You. It Works pERFECTLY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel pretty confident with my assumption that you are referring to the arrow keys on the keyboard. And as you say you already have working code for when a textbox is focused, I also assume you are using `onkeydown` (or one of the similar ones) already. So the solution is to add the event listener to the `document` instead.

Like this for example:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    // Your existing code goes here.
}
```

You need to use `onkeydown` if you want to detect arrow keys.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3n35zgrg/)

Answer (score 1):

If by forward and back keys you mean the arrow keys, this is how you can do it!

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;
switch(e.which || e.keyCode) {
    case 37: // left
    break;

    case 38: // up
    break;

    case 39: // right
    break;

    case 40: // down
    break;

    default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
}
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeydown` as this should work for all browsers. I don't think `onkeypress` will work with google chrome for the arrow key events.

- 38 = Up Arrow
- 40 = Down Arrow

To find more you can use `console.log(event.keyCode);` in your `onkeydown` function to log the key codes to your browsers console.

```js
function MyFunc() {
  alert("Key up or down!");
}
document.onkeydown = function() {
  if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) {
    MyFunc();
  }
}
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!